# Release to Sonatype remains in Staging repo

Tags: maven, sonatype

Recently I started to publish my project to the Sonatype repository, but when I did perform a release, I can see from my build log that it is indeed successfully released to the staging:

```
info]   published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0-javadoc.jar
[info]  published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0-javadoc.jar.asc
[info]  published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0.pom.asc
[info]  published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0.jar
[info]  published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0.pom
[info]  published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0-sources.jar
[info]  published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0.jar.asc
[info]  published csv-parser_2.12 to https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/bigelectrons/joesan/csv-parser_2.12/0.2.0/csv-parser_2.12-0.2.0-sources.jar.asc
[success] Total time: 155 s, completed Apr 26, 2019 7:02:16 AM
```

But I could not yet see my project in Sonatype nexus. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For help with this create an issue at https://issues.sonatype.org in the "community support - open source hosting" project.